# Name for noir-esque art style in the Burial at Sea promotional art?

Tags: illustration, style, style-identification

BioShock Infinite: Burial at Sea Episode One has a very cool illustration for the cover artwork:

[image: Burial at Sea Episode One cover]

I initially would say its art style is "noir" but when I did a [Google Images search](http://www.google.com/search?q=noir+art&tbm=isch) for "noir art" it came up with images that had some similar elements, but they were not very similar to the style above:

[image: Google Images search for "noir art"]

Is there a name for this kind of illustration's style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting. Not entirely sure what part of the style you are after, but I am going to take your *noir* as a hint.

Actually, I think you are pretty close in your search, but I think you need to use **"film noir poster".** That will give you a lot of stuff like this:

[image]

Another search term is "pulp paperback cover" or **"pulp fiction"**. This is the classic name for paperbacks with simple stories, usually detetctive-ish stuff (pulp refers to wood pulp, the cheap material for producing paperbacks.Hence, **pulp fiction**). Here is what you might find:

[image]

[image]

Clearly, your image is a modern version of this style; it is softer, more digital in the lines. But this might get you started.

---

**Edit:**

I could not resist, you might like [**this site, with pulp-noir covers**](http://pulpcovers.com/noir-paperback-cover-paintings/#4) Here is an example from that site, pulp-noir paintings:

[image]

Comment: +1 the main thing in the sample not covered by "noir" is the arrangement of different elements including faces over a paint like pattern, which is classic 1960s film poster style

Comment: @user568458 agreed; the example the OP shows is a "mashup" in a way, and a little tricky to pinpoint to one "style". It is clearly a modern take, but the text and font-choices are all on its own.

Comment: Actually I think this is a pretty good answer and provides the OP with further resources.